# Запуск таймера с другого контроллера

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть два контроллера. На первом в label отображается таймер, который можно запустить как с первого контроллера, так и со второго по нажатию на кнопку старта. На втором контроллере таймер не отображается. Как реализовать старт из первого контроллера понятно, а вот как из второго запнулся и не могу сообразить...

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var liveTimer = Timer()
var secondsLeft: Int = 1200
var liveTimerRun = false
var minutes: Int = 0
var seconds: Int = 0

func updateTimer(_ runningTimer: Timer) {
    secondsLeft -= 1
    if secondsLeft == 0 {
         label. .text = "00:00"
         liveTimerRun = false
    } else {
         minutes = (secondsLeft % 3600) / 60
         seconds = (secondsLeft % 3600) % 60
         label.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
   }
}

@IBAction func startTimerInFirstController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if liveTimerRun == false {
        liveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        liveTimerRun = true
    }
}
```

При добавлении старта таймера в экшин стартовой кнопки на втором контроллере, приложение падает, это и логично. Ссылка селектора обозначает первый контроллер. А активируем на втором, поменяв в записи на второй контроллер, вылезит ошибка в updateTimer и тд

```
@IBAction func startTimerInSecondController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if liveTimerRun == false {
        liveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        liveTimerRun = true
    }
}
```

Как реализовать запуск таймера в startTimerInSecondController? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно несколько вариантов, но легче всего будет использовать `NotificationCenter`. Во втором контроллере код по нажатию на кнопку:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("TriggerMyTimer"), object: nil)
```

В первом контроллере во `viewDidLoad`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(startTimerInFirstController), name: NSNotification.Name("TriggerMyTimer"), object: nil) //подписываемся
```

и в классе:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) //отписываемся
}
```

Что происходит: во втором контроллере после нажатия на кнопку посылается `Notification`, в первом она принимается и выполняется метод, который прописан в `#selector()`.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно